# Android App Closed after Opening without build error

Tags: android, kotlin, logcat, noclassdeffounderror, android-build

When I launched the apk on test phone, the app hanged and crashed.
How can I fix it?

I am a beginner in android

the console said :

> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s

---

````
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10089(com.angopapo.datooapp) identical 1 line
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10089(com.angopapo.datooapp) identical 3 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1495)
I/gopapo.datooap: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.angopapo.datooapp, PID: 7172
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.datooapp.app.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.datooapp.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Ge-OIFCx8dkSbMgu7ZYf6Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Ge-OIFCx8dkSbMgu7ZYf6Q==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Ge-OIFCx8dkSbMgu7ZYf6Q==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1069)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.datooapp.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Ge-OIFCx8dkSbMgu7ZYf6Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Ge-OIFCx8dkSbMgu7ZYf6Q==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Ge-OIFCx8dkSbMgu7ZYf6Q==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:50)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1120)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
    ```

I see  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:` Didn't find class `"com.example.datooapp.app.Application"` 
mean that that the class name is wrong? 

I have typed in: `com.angopapo.datooapp` as package name, 

I found the name under: `build.gradle`:
````

compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.angopapo.datooapp"
```

or where find I the right name? or is there any other cause?

Update:
Thank you for your help <3

here the logcat:

```
2021-02-18 12:45:34.063 6178-6178/? I/gopapo.datooap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2021-02-18 12:45:34.335 6178-6178/? W/gopapo.datooap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
2021-02-18 12:45:34.645 6178-6178/com.angopapo.datooapp I/gopapo.datooap: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2021-02-18 12:45:36.304 6178-6178/com.angopapo.datooapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-02-18 12:45:36.307 6178-6178/com.angopapo.datooapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.angopapo.datooapp, PID: 6178
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.datooapp.app.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.datooapp.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Nw8AOQZhqW2yTX5skdLjHg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Nw8AOQZhqW2yTX5skdLjHg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Nw8AOQZhqW2yTX5skdLjHg==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1069)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.datooapp.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Nw8AOQZhqW2yTX5skdLjHg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Nw8AOQZhqW2yTX5skdLjHg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.angopapo.datooapp-Nw8AOQZhqW2yTX5skdLjHg==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:50)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1120)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5842) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

and here the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.angopapo.datooapp">

    <!--General-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!--Internet-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <!--Storage-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!--Sensors and Device-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!--Location-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--Account and Notifications-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.angopapo.datooapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <!--Badge and Shortcut-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.angopapo.datooapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.datooapp.app.Application"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.datooapp.app.SplashScreen"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeApp.NoWindowPreview">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

        <!--Network monitoring-->

        <service
            android:name="com.example.datooapp.modules.merlin.MerlinService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- Google Setup -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api_key_geo" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id"/>

        <!-- Facebook Integration-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--Push notifications services-->
        <service
            android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseMessagingService"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.datooapp.pushNotifications.CustomPushReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.datooapp.authUtils.AngopapoLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <meta-data
                android:name="AngopapoLogin.APP_LOGO"
                android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="AngopapoLogin.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="AngopapoLogin.PARSE_LOGIN_EMAIL_AS_USERNAME"
                android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="AngopapoLogin.PARSE_LOGIN_HELP_TEXT"
                android:value="@string/password_reset_text"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="AngopapoLogin.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH"
                android:value="6"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="AngopapoLogin.FACEBOOK_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="AngopapoLogin.TWITTER_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="false"/>
            <!-- We reference a string-array resource here, so we must use android:resource -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="AngopapoLogin.FACEBOOK_LOGIN_PERMISSIONS"
                android:resource="@array/my_facebook_permissions"/>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.auth.WelcomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.authUtils.AngopapoSignupActivity" />

        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.auth.FacebookLink" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.app.BaseActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.datooapp.app.DispatchActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.uploads.UploadsActivity" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.datooapp.modules.instagram.InstagramAuthActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.nearby.ManualLocationActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.popularity.PopularityActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.payments.PaymentsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.encounters.LikedYouActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.encounters.MutualAttractionActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.profile.PhotosViewerActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.basicInfo.BasicInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.account.AccountActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.accountPreferences.AccountPreferencesActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.accountPreferences.SettingsPrivacyActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.accountPreferences.SettingsInvisibleModeActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.accountPreferences.SettingsNotificationsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.WebUrlsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.about.AboutActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.about.AboutAppActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.settings.BlockedUsersActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.profile.ReportBlockActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.profile.EditProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.connections.FeatureActivationActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.connections.ChatActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.calls.CallActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.connections.IncomingActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MyAppCompatDialogTheme"/>

        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.live.WalletActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.live.LiveActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.live.LiveStreamingActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.profile.PhotoViewerActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.datooapp.home.calls.VoiceCallActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you should look `logcat` for errors. add the error in you question so we can help you

Comment: Can you share your android manifest file ?

Comment: thanks for youre help , i have the thread updated with android manifest and logcat :)

edit: when i see the text: 

com.example.datooapp.app.Application , 
i think i must replace

Comment: does com.example.datooapp.app.Application exists in your project ?

Comment: thanks for youre help , i have the thread updated with android manifest and logcat :)

edit: when i see the text: 

com.example.datooapp.app.Application , 
i think i must replace: com.example.datooapp.app.Application

With: com.angopapo.datooapp.app.Application  ?? and this in each line ? or how is the best way? , thanks for all :)

No i think not @ trixo, it was a buyed template , i think the right is: package="com.angopapo.datooapp">

Comment: I see, IT is actually a process to rename the package name, you can't just rename it like that let me see, just to be sure, 

Your original package name was   com.example.datooapp.app.Application
and you wanted to rename it to com.angopapo.datooapp 
is that right ?

Comment: i rename it to : com.angopapo.datooapp.app.Application
after that is the app loading but only black screen but not crashing

Comment: can you go to the point before you renamed it for a first time ?  It would be easier to guide you through process of renaming app from working stage rather than finding out what is broken

Comment: Yeah no problem , have revert the changes , how then start now?